# Screen reader that logs text (for accessibility testing)?

Tags: windows, accessibility, screen-reader

Does anyone know of a screen reader for Windows that writes text to a log instead of actually reading it out? This is for accessibility testing. I know how to directly access the automation tree, but I want to be able to see what screen readers would actually say.

**EDIT:** *(not enough rep to answer my own question)* [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org/) has a "Speech Viewer" which does this. Right click on the taskbar icon, go to tools -> speech viewer.

Comment: Not sure about a rep limit back then, but I think you should be able to create a self-answer now :)